# Laravel 5.7 Auth Problem can't get access

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i can't get access to my login auth even if everything was fine until i did a migration refresh to start from 0 testing everything if it was fine.
i created a user but when i try to login it show just error as if my data was incorrect.

```
    public function login(Request $request) {
        if($request->isMethod('post')){

            $data = $request->input();
        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']])) {
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard');

    }else{
       return redirect('admin/')->with ('msg_error','Pseudo ou mot de passe invalide');

    }
}

        return view ('admin.admin_login');
    }
```

[My data from PMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQDP1.png)

this is my login form

```
    <form id="loginform" class="form-vertical" method="post" action="{{ url('admin') }} ">@csrf
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="main_input_box">
                    <span class="add-on bg_lg"><i class="icon-user"> </i></span><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Utulisateur" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="main_input_box">
                    <span class="add-on bg_ly"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de Passe" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <span class="pull-left"><a href="#" class="flip-link btn btn-info" id="to-recover">Mot de passe oublié ?</a></span>
            <span class="pull-right"><input type="submit" value="Se connecter" class="btn btn-success" /></span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The user Creation file :

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->role = $data['role'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user->save();
```

Data from input :

```
array(3) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "2h4nA3WuLSlWfpInCH45eUZqtyvHWEg5K7aYWC83"
  ["email"]=>
  string(14) "test@email.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(6) "000000"
}
```

and data after using hash check

```
    object(App\User)#266 (27) {
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "name"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "email"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "level"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "status"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "activation_code"
  }
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "remember_token"
  }
  ["connection":protected]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
  ["table":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["withCount":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test1"
    ["role"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "test@email.com"
    ["email_verified_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 00:00:00"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$1FRa6tZz9Q.NycSVEickte/zBXfLjSlONH0Byiu363bBtQZVXLbwS"
    ["remember_token"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test1"
    ["role"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "test@email.com"
    ["email_verified_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 00:00:00"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$1FRa6tZz9Q.NycSVEickte/zBXfLjSlONH0Byiu363bBtQZVXLbwS"
    ["remember_token"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
  }
  ["changes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["rememberTokenName":protected]=>
  string(14) "remember_token"
}
bool(false)
object(App\User)#279 (27) {
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "name"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "email"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "level"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "status"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "activation_code"
  }
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "remember_token"
  }
  ["connection":protected]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
  ["table":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["withCount":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test1"
    ["role"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "test@email.com"
    ["email_verified_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 00:00:00"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$1FRa6tZz9Q.NycSVEickte/zBXfLjSlONH0Byiu363bBtQZVXLbwS"
    ["remember_token"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test1"
    ["role"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "test@email.com"
    ["email_verified_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 00:00:00"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$1FRa6tZz9Q.NycSVEickte/zBXfLjSlONH0Byiu363bBtQZVXLbwS"
    ["remember_token"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-21 11:39:51"
  }
  ["changes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
  ["rememberTokenName":protected]=>
  string(14) "remember_token"
}
bool(false)
```

i don't know where is the problem

Comment: When you run database refresh, you need to register with your account to be able to login. Have you checked the database to see if your account you are trying to login with exists?

Comment: Can you post the stack Trace?

Comment: when i cleared the database firstly i created a new user then i tried to login

Comment: Hey there! Are you getting the input correctly? Print it out. I saw that you usede $request->input(); To retrieve data. According to documentation this should be done with `$request->all();` as `$request->input('');` method expects a name attribute string as first parameter

Comment: array(3) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "2h4nA3WuLSlWfpInCH45eUZqtyvHWEg5K7aYWC83"
  ["email"]=>
  string(14) "test@email.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(6) "000000"
}

Comment: How about the `Auth::attempt()`? Does it get called?

Comment: `$user = User::first();  var_dump($user, Hash::check('000000', $user->password));`

Comment: yeah by use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: Are the email and password fields the name of the fields in database? Have you customized the default username logic? Meaning that you have defined some other field to use when checking for username ie defined `username()` method in the logincontroller.

Comment: @SilentK1D your password doesn't match according to the false return of the hash check

Comment: @Devon check plz the edited question after i used hash::check var_dump

Comment: @user3647971 yeah i tried a new login page by me just for admin panel

Comment: @Devon how should i correct things here ?

Comment: @SilentK1D Use password reset :P but you dont have access to the test email?

Comment: Or create new user and try it out

Comment: @user3647971 i deleted this one and create a new one but the problem is the same do you have teamviwer

Comment: @SilentK1D No I don't, but the problem is really simple... just something you have overlooked in database, migrations, or any custom code you have added for the authentication

Comment: @user3647971 okay i will try and if i found anything i will post the solution here

Comment: @SilentK1D Use: `php artisan migrate:fresh` on laravel folder. It's different from the `refresh` and doesnt screw you up with database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the false return of `Hash::check('000000', $user->password);`, the password is not a hashed value of `000000` in the database.

You can reset the password with

```
$user->update(['password' => bcrypt('000000')]);
```

Bcrypt is a helper function for Hash::make.  Using `artisan tinker` will make this easy as it provides you an interactive console to run commands.

Comment: the same problem even after using bcrypt in my user creation file

Comment: Does hash check return true?

Comment: with bool(false) at the end

Comment: You still have some issue with your hash then.  You don't need to do the entire var dump if you're using tinker.

Comment: but what give me a headache is that i tried migration refresh to clear all the database then i created new user to test the app from the start and this problem just show up from no where

Comment: Try this: `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: Did you run the update I suggested or did you just run the same user creation file?

Comment: Refresh artisan command seems to be really annoying since you have to do ups and downs for all migrations

Comment: `migrate:fresh` doesnt care about the down methods of migrations, It drops all tables and just runs the up methods

Comment: @user3647971 is the same problem

Comment: @SilentK1D well, only thing I can think of left to check is that the bcrypt really is the hashing function used by the auth check. Because it seems like the creation and check uses different hashes

Comment: @SilentK1D or the username field is the name, not email

Comment: @user3647971 i used the bcrypt in writing password on database

Comment: `protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }` this is my user creation function from default authentication of laravel

Comment: `protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }` And my validator for formdata

Comment: `use RegistersUsers;` also this is included in the same class as user generation

Comment: i tried the user creation default of laravel to make a new user but when i tried to login from the default login page of laravel it show me an error

Comment: Instead of creating a new user with your script... did you try just resetting the password like I showed in my answer and then running hash check?  It seems like you're overcomplicating this..

Comment: @Devon i tried the user creation default of laravel to make a new user but when i tried to login from the default login page of laravel it show me an error hhhh

Comment: But you still haven't tried running what I suggested an hour ago?   Run tinker, execute the update command and re-execute the Hash::check.  This should take 30s..

Comment: @Devon its the same hash in my database

Comment: @Devon  the problem is on the hash of the password after i used tinker to hash a password and modified my database and tried to log in everything was good

Comment: so i cant find a solution for this